# Spark Streaming output mode "memory" showing none records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am running spark streaming code in VS Code editor and I'm using memory as my data sink and the output mode is complete.

When I try to see the result from the memory table it's showing None output.

Any help would be appreciated

```
import sys
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('Max_Stock in complete mode').getOrCreate()

sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')

schema = StructType([StructField('Date', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('Open', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('High', DoubleType(), True),
                    StructField('Low', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('Close', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('Adjusted Close', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('Volume', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('Name', StringType(), True)
                    ])

input_stream = """path"""
stockPricesDf = sparkSession.readStream.option('header', 'true').schema(schema).csv(input_stream)
print(' ')
print('Is the stream ready?')
print(stockPricesDf.isStreaming)


print(' ')
print('Schema of the input stream')
print(stockPricesDf.printSchema())

upDaysDf = stockPricesDf.select("Name", "Date","High", "Open", "Close").where("Open > Close") 
upDays_max = upDaysDf.groupBy('Name').max('High')               

query = upDays_max.writeStream.outputMode('complete').format('memory').queryName('datatable')\
            .option('truncate', 'false') \
            .option('numRows', 5) \
            .start() \
            .awaitTermination()
SparkSession.sql("select * from datatable ").show(5)
```

Comment: remove ```awaitTermination``` and check ??

Comment: @Srinivas I removed awaitTermination  and run the code again, still showing None result and after  couple of minutes i am seeing a different error TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5dea84cd8be6> in <module>
     55     .start() \
     56 
---> 57 SparkSession.sql("select * from datatable").show()

TypeError: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'